# python (deI) statement and python behavior

Tags: python

When a del statement is issued:

> del var

Shouldn't it be removed from the list of known variable and shouldn't the python interpreter spit out "unresolved reference" error?

Or is it simply just deleting the object and leaving the name (var) not pointing anywhere? Why would that kind of behavior be useful? In what cases?

Also I am talking simply about deleting a single variable. Not del list[3] or alike.

note: I am asking if this python's behavior is meant that way. And in what cases, it would be still useful.

EDIT: Charles Addis gave a detailed explanation. I also admit my mistake that I mistook the pycharm behavior as official python's. I am now trying out ipython along with official python interactive shell. Despite this being my mistake, I am glad that I learnt a lot about python variables along with some python debug commands.

Comment: If you go `del var;var` that's exactly what happens. Do you expect `del var` to try to return the deleted variable?

Comment: Umm... It already does what you suggest. Raises `NameError` or `UnboundLocalError` depending on context. Once `del var` is executed, the local name of `var` is gone. If other names referenced the same object, then the object will still exist, just not under that name.

Comment: I found out the hard way that using pycharm actually mislead me into this. python interpreter does it like you guys are saying. I am now trying out ipython besides the stock official python interactive shell. I didn't know what I was missing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you're asking, as clearly thats what happens...

```
>>> x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
>>> x = 10
>>> 'x' in vars()
True
>>> vars()['x']
10
>>> del x
>>> 'x' in vars()
False
>>> x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

As you can see, Python allows access to valid identifiers from the current scope in `locals()` (and `vars()` works similarly - there is also `dir(obj)` which will display attributes of an object)... So del essentially removes it from memory, which removes it from the data structures returned by these functions as well. So the identifier is no longer valid. It's not like in C where you might free some memory and set the value to `NULL`.

```
>>> x = 10
>>> def func():
...   global x
...   del x
...
>>> x
10
>>> func()
>>> x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
>>>
```

### Update:

Raymond made a good point when he mentioned that the object itself (read: the actual data in memory that the identifier points too, for lack of a more detailed explanation) is only freed when it's reference count goes to 0. IMO he could have done a better job detailing this in the python interpreter, so I'll have a go at it.

We'll use the ID function to prove this:

```
Help on built-in function id in module __builtin__:

id(...)
    id(object) -> integer

    Return the identity of an object.  This is guaranteed to be unique among
    simultaneously existing objects.  (Hint: it's the object's memory address.)
```

Pay attention to whats going on here, you'll see that for immutable types, different variables reference the same memory (strings are immutable in python and are interned, which means only one copy of each unique string is stored -- in ruby, symbols are interned strings).

```
>>> import sys
>>> x = 10     # 10 is a common value, probably exists in memory already
>>> sys.getrefcount(x)
26
>>> id(x)      # memory location of x
140266396760096
>>> y = x
>>> id(y) == id(x)
True
>>> z = 10
>>> id(z) == id(y) == id(x)
True
>>> sys.getrefcount(y)
28
>>> sys.getrefcount(z)
28
>>> del y, z
>>> sys.getrefcount(x)
26
>>> del x
>>> x = 'charlie'
>>> id(x)
4442795056
>>> y = 'charlie'
>>> z = x
>>> id(x) == id(y) == id(z)
True
>>> sys.getrefcount(x)
4
>>> sys.getrefcount(y)
4
>>> sys.getrefcount(z)
4
>>> del y
>>> del x
>>> sys.getrefcount(z)     # will be two because this line is an additional reference
2
>>> id(z)                  # pay attention to this memory location because this 
4442795056                 # is the last remaining reference to 'charlie', and
>>> del z                  # when it goes out of scope 'charlie' is removed from
>>>                        # memory.
>>> id('charlie')          # This has a different memory location because 'charlie'
4442795104                 # had to be re-created.
```

First we set the identifier 'x' == 10, a common integer value. Since 10 is such a common value, it's almost guaranteed that something in the processes memory already has that value. Since integers are immutable in python, we only ever need one copy of each unique value stored in memory. In this case, there are 24 other references to 10 in memory. Setting `x = 10` creates the 25th reference, and calling `sys.getrefcount(x)` is the 26th reference (though it quickly goes out of scope). When we set `y = 10` and `z = x`, we know that they all point to the same data because they all have the same memory location. Calling `del` alters the reference count, but even when all 3 are deleted the integer 10 still exists in memory.

Next we create set `x = 'charlie'`, followed by `y = 'charlie'`, and finally `z = x`. You can see all of these variables have the same memory address. Once we delete all of these variables there are no more references to `'charlie'`. We can verify this by calling `id('charlie')` which will produce a different memory address meaning the string did not exist in memory when we called that function.

One more thing to note is the location of `'charlie'` and `10` in memory. `10` has a significantly higher memory address than Charlie does. This is because they exist in different locations of memory. `'charlie'` exists on the heap whereas `10` exists on the stack.

```
>>> hex(id(10))         # high address, this is on the stack
'0x7f9250c0b820'
>>> hex(id('charlie'))  # lower address, this is on the heap
'0x108cfac60
```

Comment: Nitpick: `locals()` (and equivalently, no argument `vars`) lets you view the valid identifiers and their values, but it's not what Python actually uses for much of anything. Python doesn't actually store locals in a `dict` most of the time, it's just being made for you on demand when you call `locals()` (`dict` lookups for every local variable access would slow everything down, as would generating the `dict` when not needed). It's not necessary to describing the issue in any event; the `NameError` makes it clear it's gone.

Comment: Ah ok. I forgot python does things on demand. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Also, using pycharm mislead me to that initial conclusion because it doesn't print out error after del statement like python interpreter does.

Comment: @shadowranger yeah I know, I was just giving it to him high level. Those are just interfaces to access the process data.

Comment: @theMobDog this is why I don't use IDEs. When I first got into software they were invaluable, but after working for a while, professionally, using Vim... I'm unable to use anything else. In my opinion, the terminal is a much stronger IDE than any IDE I've ever used. You get the power of the shell, interactive python interpreter (ipython is great), and lightning fast development in vim.

Comment: @Charles Now I can see why python variables are just tags or names. In C/C++, when you declare a variable, you create a container, and then you store data in it. (A little off topic but) What buffles me is why some objects have so many references. Something like short numbers tend to have so many references. More unique numbers have less references. A lot less. (You don't have to answer that. just my observation). But thanks for detailed explanation!

Comment: @theMobDog I know, I have experience programming in C and C++. I'm not exactly sure what the process memory of a python interpreter looks like, but I imagine that there are many values in memory that are equal to 10, or basically the small integers. Not sure what they are.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't it be removed from the list of known variable and shouldn't
>   the python interpreter spit out "unresolved reference" error?

This is exactly what happens. Once you `del` something, the next reference to it will raise `NameError`.

> Or is it simply just deleting the object and leaving the name (var)
>   not pointing anywhere? Why would that kind of behavior be useful? In
>   what cases?

In Python, things are a bit different. There are no "variables" as you might be used to in other languages.

There is the object space, where data lives - and the namespace, where *names* live.

*names* are what we normally refer to in other languages as *variables* but in Python they are simply labels to an object in the data space.

Once the label (name) is removed with `del`, its simply taking away the label that points to the object. The object (which has the value) remains; unless its not referred to by any other name, in which case Python will then garbage collect it. Names are just lightweight labels that point to objects in the object space, and are the only way we can access those objects.

Here is an example to illustrate this:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> y = x
>>> del x
>>> y
5
```

Now I deleted `x`, but since `y` is still pointing to the same object as `x` (the integer `5`), it remains and I can access it again; but if I try to access `x`:

```
>>> x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: Thank you. I mistook the pycharm's behavior with that of python. In pycharm, after del statement. you can still check for the variable even tho it no longer defined.

Comment: It now makes a lot of sense now the way things are set up with python names/variables and the objects. A lot less complicated compared to say C/C++.

Answer (score 1):

The "del" removes the name from the current namespace. If the underlying object has its reference count drop to zero, then the object itself is freed.

```
>>> import sys
>>> x = 123456
>>> y = x               # create a second reference to the number
>>> dir()               # known variables include "x" and "y"
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'sys', 'x', 'y']
>>> sys.getrefcount(x)
3
>>> del x               # remove "x" as a known variable
>>> dir()               # known variables includes only "y"
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'sys', 'y']
>>> sys.getrefcount(y)  # reference count is now lower by 1
2
>>> del y               # remove "y" as a known variable
>>> dir()               # known variables no longer include "x" and "y"
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'sys']
>>> x                   # unresolved variable raises a "NameError"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    x                  # unresolved variable raises a "NameError"
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I always wanted to know what things are under the hood. These will come useful later.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger -- I updated my answer to give more detail to yours